# How do you debug a Microsoft Store Package?

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, native-code

I've got a simple UWP client on a simple web application.  When I run it with the **Debug** configuration, it works great, when I run with the **Release**, it works great.  However, when I create a package for the Microsoft Store and deploy it locally, it crashes when I try to bring up a certain class of documents.

I've tried to place a pop-up message box on the unhandled instructions, but don't get any pop-up.

I've tried to attach to it with the Visual Studio debugger, but all I get is a message that Visual Studio can't debug Native code.  It appears the **.Net Native Tool Chain** flag is the only difference between the working and crashing version of my application.

Any ideas/clues on how to debug this issue?

Comment: Is it actually "native" code? What language was it written in? If you used C# did you use an AOT compiler?

Comment: Thanks, I updated the code to be more specific.  We're talking about the .NEt Native Tool Chain option.

Answer (score 0):

OK.  This ate up a day of my life.  It turns out there's at least one class of errors that isn't even considered a warning by the RTL, but is an unhandled exception in the .NET Native code.  I was using a style in a control that didn't have the proper base control.  Here's the usage:

```
  <gfcontrols:PriceControl DataContext="{Binding Path=LastPrice}"
                           Style="{StaticResource PriceStyle}"/>
```

And here is the style:

```
  <Style x:Key="PriceStyle"
         TargetType="controls:QuantityControl">
    <Setter Property="Format"
            Value="#,##0.00;-#,##0.00"/>
  </Style>
```

Note that the **QuantityControl** isn't an acceptable target type for a **PriceControl** as they are both children of a **ContentControl**.  Running this in the Visual Studio debugger didn't cause any warnings or even informational messages.  However, once I loaded it through the [Hockey Crash Diagnostics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jqq4SbMXDSM&t=996s), I was able to finally get the message:

> Cannot apply a Style with TargetType
>   'GammaFour.Views.Controls.DecimalControl' to an object of type
>   'GammaFour.Views.Controls.PriceControl'. [Line: 0 Position: 0]

So, the answer is: you need to get familiar with the Hockey utility mentioned in the link if you expect to diagnose UWP application errors because, apparently, **not everything that's allowed in the RTL is allowed in the native code**.

Comment: Hello @Donald Airey, While reading your post i was wondering how do you setup your log system. Maybe with a good logger and the proper settings you could find the source of the problem much faster.

Comment: @NickPolyderopoulos - No, logging using Serilog didn't catch the crash or the mismatch between the target controls in the styles.

Answer (score -1):

You can't debug a release package, but you can extract the exception code by accessing the error report located somewhere in

`C:\Users\All Users\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive`

Try to use some diagnostic tools to open the `wer` file such as [Diagnostic Data Viewer](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9N8WTRRSQ8F7) or [AppCrashView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/app_crash_view.html) and look over the exception code.

Comment: This file had nothing of interest in it.